# How I remove' Current/Old Password' section from ChangePassword control in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

How I remove 'Current/Old Password' section from ChangePassword control in asp.net.
When I remove this section,I get following error.

*ChangeUserPassword: ChangePasswordTemplate does not contain an IEditableTextControl with ID CurrentPassword for the current password.*

I only need 'New Password' and 'Confirm new password' section

**Edit_*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

```
<asp:ChangePassword ID="ChangeUserPassword" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"
        RenderOuterTable="false">

        <ChangePasswordTemplate>        
            <span class="failureNotification">
                <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </span>
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ChangeUserPasswordValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification"
                ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup" />
            <div class="accountInfo">
                <fieldset class="changePassword">
                    <legend>Account Information</legend>
                    <%--<p>
                        <asp:Label ID="CurrentPasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="CurrentPassword">Old Password:</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="CurrentPassword" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="CurrentPasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="CurrentPassword"
                            CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Old Password is required."
                            ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </p>--%>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="NewPasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="NewPassword">New Password:</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="NewPassword" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NewPasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="NewPassword"
                            CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="New Password is required." ToolTip="New Password is required."
                            ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="ConfirmNewPasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ConfirmNewPassword">Confirm New Password:</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmNewPassword" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmNewPasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmNewPassword"
                            CssClass="failureNotification" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Confirm New Password is required."
                            ToolTip="Confirm New Password is required." ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:CompareValidator ID="NewPasswordCompare" runat="server" ControlToCompare="NewPassword"
                            ControlToValidate="ConfirmNewPassword" CssClass="failureNotification" Display="Dynamic"
                            ErrorMessage="The Confirm New Password must match the New Password entry." ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup">*</asp:CompareValidator>
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
                <p class="submitButton">
                    <%--<asp:Button ID="CancelPushButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"/>--%>
                    <a href="Default.aspx" title="Back">&lt;&lt;Back</a>
                    <asp:Button ID="ChangePasswordPushButton" runat="server" Text="Change Password" 
                        ValidationGroup="ChangeUserPasswordValidationGroup" 
                        onclick="ChangePasswordPushButton_Click" />
                </p>
            </div>
        </ChangePasswordTemplate>
    </asp:ChangePassword>
```

Comment: Can you show the markup where you removed the section you are talking about?

Comment: The ChangePasswordTemplate actually *requires* and  `IEditableTextControl` with ID **CurrentPasword**. An `IEditableTextControl` can be for example a TextBox, or any other control implementing that interface. You can read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.changepassword.changepasswordtemplate.aspx

Comment: I don't need this.How I remove.

Comment: Maybe you can inherit your own control from the `HiddenField` and implement the `IEditableTextControl` and then use that.

Comment: Changing built-in controls can be tricky business, you should consider creating your own functionality if built-in does not suit you.

Comment: For future reference, here is a post with a solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011621/change-user-password-in-asp-net-forms-authentication